# Basemap Widgets

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

[image]
I am looking for a fancy Basemap plugin to use with the ArcGIS Javascript API. Something along the lines of the Basemap Widget (see image below) available in the Flex Viewer would be great.
Anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Basemap Toggle (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_toggle.html) and the Basemap Gallery (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_basemap.html) for examples or their widgets?

If you use the image you have and assign click events to each 'button', you can change the basemap using code similar to:

`map.setBasemap('topo')`

You can use 'satellie', 'streets', 'hybrid', 'gray', 'national-geographic', 'osm', and probably a few newer basemaps instead of the 'topo'.

As for an existing one, I have no idea but creating your own shouldn't be too cumbersome.

You could create your own buttons in the similar manner and use their click events to change the CSS and assign a new basemap everytime.